# Wordpress cannot find a link

Tags: wordpress

I have a link in wordpress website. However, I cannot find the link to edit. I try to find it in pages and in template. I tried to edit a page but the page is empty. So where does wordpress placed my link? Is it in database or somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: I have a homepage. But when I goto Pages and then edit the page. However the page is empty. The status of the page is published. Do I need to change the status and then edit again?

Answer (score 0):

Homepage template can be `index.php`, `home.php` or `front-page.php` located in your theme's folder.

Find out which page is being loaded as your homepage in Settings -> Reading under **Front page displays**.

All the content in WordPress should also be accessible from within your Admin Panel. You have to find that out yourself. Only people who have access to the Admin Panel knows about that. Ask the person who was responsible for this if you must.